# Power Series Solution to ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, power-series

Trying to find the general solution of the following equation:

$$2x(1+2x^2)y''-y'-24xy=0 $$
using:
$$y(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty  a_nx^{n+r}$$
r and $a_n$ are constants

I get so far as the recurrence relation but then not sure what to do
I find this to be:

$$a_{n+1}=\frac{4(n+r-2)(n+r-1)-24}{(n+r+1)-2(n+r)(n+r+1)}a_{n-1}$$

any help?

not sure what to do about $a_0$ and $a_1$

I'm sorry that this isn't well formatted.

Comment: So what values for $r$ have you gotten?

Comment: I got $(2r^2-3r)a_o$=0 so r=1.5 or r=0

Comment: but then also got $(2r^2+r+1)a_1$=0 so r=0.5 or r=-1

Comment: i don't understand what to do with 4 values, as all my examples only have 2 :S

Comment: Make sure you got the right indicial equation?  I have not worked the problem out!

Comment: When changing the indices for say n+r-1 would the sum then be from n=-1, do you know?